# What do you do with Delphi for PHP?

Tags: php, delphi

Well, I just got Delphi for PHP because we code our app in Delphi and I'm the web guy.  Go figure, it looks pretty cool and super easy, but I can't imagine making an entire website with absolute positioned labels, that would be kind of obscene, cross-browser compliant, but obscene.

Can anyone suggest good resources/usergroups/tutorials/examples/blogs/wiki's for using Delphi for PHP

I'm not new to PHP or Delphi, but I do want to justify getting this software because it seems pretty cool.

Comment: Wow... Delphi for PHP... well that just sucks.

Comment: Wow prejudice, that really stifles imagination and ingenuity.  I just said to my boss a few minutes ago:

8:38:48am To: Darin
Delphi for PHP is really really cool.

Comment: There's an irony in our company as we use Delphi 2007 to write PHP plug-ins but we don't use Delphi for PHP to develop sites. I agree with this question and have yet to find an suitable excuse to adopt Delphi for PHP either. If there are some examples for sites built with it I'd be most interested.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it helps or not, but I just finished reading an article in the PHP Architect magazine that seems to imply that Delphi for PHP has a fair bit to do with VCL4PHP.

I daresay reading up on it (maybe starting at http://www.qadram.com/vcl4php/ ) could help.

Comment: AFAIK Delphi for PHP *is* VCL4PHP.  CodeGear purchased it and added some polish and finish.

Comment: They also added a big price tag.  When it was going to be free it was interesting.  With a monster price tag on it, the reasons for using Delphi4PHP (bad name in SO many ways) or RadPHP CE as it is now called (just plain stupid name: it's not even a proper name, just 3 acronyms tacked together) are few indeed.  Which could be why they now bundle it in Studio (if you can't see something, try giving it away) except that means it's only "free" if you can stomach the eye watering price of Studio.

Answer (score 3):

You can also have a look at:

http://www.phpclasses.org/reviews/id/B0018RTNSO.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is a forum with some interesting stuff:
http://forums.delphi-php.net/

Answer (score 2):

Although it has been quite a while this product is on the market, it could not gain a momentum as expected. VCL4PHP seems a good framework but not good enough to beat the existing ones. The lack of documentation and community support are major drawbacks for D4PHP. I am trying to develop some basic web app (a todo list). And if I progress enough I'll make a blog about it.  Apart from

- http://www.qadram.com/vcl4php/ and
- http://forums.delphi-php.net
- https://forums.embarcadero.com/category.jspa?categoryID=18

you cannot find much of a resource.

Answer (score 0):

[Good list of forums and newsgroups](http://forums.delphi-php.net/embarcadero-public-delphiphp-vclforphp-components-writing/796-writing-component.html#post2376) apparently there's an active community of VCL4PHP developers at sourceforge.

Answer (score -1):

Delphi for PHP is pretty cool - it's just a shame that PHP has a very slow handling of data structures (just like Python), and therefore, you won't get a very impressive speed of your web application.

However, Delphi for PHP compares ok in speed with most other PHP-based frameworks, and it's surely good at organizing your code.